# Как объяснить получаемый результат, если не указывается initialValue у .reduce() в JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Хотелось бы понять, что происходит "под капотом" JS, когда указываешь как "0" initialValue у метода .reduce() или НЕ указываешь его вовсе.
Приведу две версии кода:

- первая, где указано значение "0" initialValue у метода .reduce()
- вторая версия, где initialValue у метода .reduce() НЕ указан.

Результаты в консоль выводятся такие:

- в первой версии: "5"
- во второй версии: "5.888888888888888"

**Вопрос: почему такая разница? Почему так получается? Возможно, ошибочный код?**

Вот версия №1:

```
const arrayNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const average = arrayNumbers.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num / arrayNumbers.length, 0)

console.log(average)//5
```

Вот версия № 2:

```
const arrayNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const average = arrayNumbers.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num / arrayNumbers.length)

console.log(average)//5.888888888888888
```

Comment: в доках про initialValue всё написано что нужно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#description

Comment: И мне кажется `/ arrayNumbers.length` правильнее применять к результату выполнения метода `.reduce`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson и это тоже 

Comment: Большое спасибо за комментарии, разобрался!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Когда мы не указываем initialValue, тогда accumulator принимает значение первого элемента. Отсюда и разница в результатах.